# Merge multiple regular expressions for date recognition

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a python 2.7.6 program that finds all the instances of dates in a input file i.e. (if a file contains "April 9th, 2014" "Tuesday" "02/14/1980" "Christmas" it will find all these in a file).  Since dates can be represented in many different ways I have separate regular expressions for the different types of dates. I want to merge all my separate regular expressions into 1 big regular expression so it finds each "type" of date in the order they appear in the file.

I have the following code to test for dates like "April 9th, 2014"

```
matches = re.findall("(?:((?:jan(?:(?:.)?|(?:uary)?)|feb(?:(?:.)?|(?:ruary)?)|mar(?:(?:.)?|(?:ch)?)|apr(?:(?:.)?|(?:il)?)|may|jun(?:(?:.)?|(?:e)?)|jul(?:(?:.)?|(?:y)?)|aug(?:(?:.)?|(?:gust)?)|sep(?:(?:.)?|(?:ept(?:(?:.)?))?|(?:tember)?)|oct(?:(?:.)?|(?:ober)?)|nov(?:(?:.)?|(?:ember)?)|dec(?:(?:.)?|(?:ember)?)) (?:[123][0-9]|[1-9])[ \t\r\f\v]?(?:rd|st|th)?(?:,)?[ \t\r\f\v]?(?:[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])?)|(?:(?:[0]?[1-9])|(?:[1][0-2]))[-/](?:(?:[012]?[0-9])|(?:[3][01]))[/-][12][0-9][0-9][0-9])",fileText,re.IGNORECASE)
print matches
```

On the next line I match for dates similar to 02/14//1980 like this

```
matches = re.findall("(?:(?:[0]?[1-9])|(?:[1][0-2]))[-/](?:(?:[012]?[0-9])|(?:[3][01]))[/-][12][0-9][0-9][0-9]",fileText, re.IGNORECASE)
print matches
```

I want to merge them into one regular expression. I tried doing

```
matches = re.findall("(?:first regular expression|second regular expression)", textFile, re.IGNORECASE)
print matches
```

But this just printed all dates like "April 9th, 2014" (which was what the first regular expression was for) and  '' for all dates that look like "02/14/1980" (which was what the second regular expression.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in helping me figure out how to make 2 regex's into 1.

Comment: Don't do this with *only* RegEx if you're trying to handle an abundant number of different formats *and* validate.

Comment: I've already written the individual types, now I'm just trying to merge the different regular expressions. So I don't think it would be a good use of my time to re-write this. But good point and I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

What about just checking each input line against each regex?

```
for line in input_file:
    regex1 = re.findall(pattern,line)
    regex2 = re.findall(pattern,line)
    if len(regex1) > 0:
        for item in regex1:
            print(item)
    if len(regex2) > 0:
        for item in regex2:
            print(item)
```